# MQ - COA correlation issue after change of remote destination from Queue to Topic

Tags: ibm-mq, correlation, jms-topic

Seeking for an advise on the below faced COA correlation issue.

**Background**: there is an application A which is feeding data to an application B via MQ (nothing special - remote queue def pointing to the local q def on remote QM). Where the sending app A is requesting COAs. That is a stable setup working for years:

App A -> QM.A[Q1] -channel-> QM.B[Q2] -> App B

Here:

- Q1 is a remote q def pointing to the Q2.

**Problem**: there is an application C which requires exactly the same data feed which A is sending to B via MQ. => it is required to duplicate data feed considering the following constraint.

**Constraint**: **neither code, nor app config of applications A and B could be changed** - duplication of the data feed from A to B should be transparent for applications A and B - A puts messages to the same queue Q1 on QM.A; B gets messages from the same queue Q2 on the QM.B

**Proposed solution**: duplicate the feed on the MQ layer by creation of the Topic/subscirbers configuration on the QM of the app B:

App A -> QM.A[Q1] -channel-> QM.B[QA->T->{S2,S3}->{Q2,Q3}] -> {App B, QM.C[Q4] -> App C}

Here:

- Q1 - has the rname property updated to point to the QA for Topic
  instead of Q2
- QA - Queue Alias for Topic T
- T - Topic
- S2, S3 - subscribers publishing data to the Q2 and Q3
- Q2 - unchanged, the same local queue definition where App B consumes from
- Q3 - remote queue definition pointing to the Q4
- Q4 - local queue definition on the QM.C, the queue with copy of messages sent from A to B

With this set up duplication of the messages from the app A to the app B and C works fine. 
But ... there is an issue.

**Issue**: application A is not able to correlate COAs and that is the problem. 
I'm not sure if app A is not able to correlate COAs at all, or (what is more likely guess) it is not able to correlate additional COAs e.g. from the QM.C

Any idea or advise is very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc. QM.B is MQ v.7.1. I need to doublecheck what app A is looking at, not an easy thing though since have no source codes. </br> Is there a way to suppress sending of one of COAs ?

Comment: Likely "application A" sends a message with the reporting option set to get a COA and specifies a `ReplyToQueue` and `ReplyToQmgr`  and records the `MessageId` of the sent message.  When the message hits the local queue in the original working use case the COA is generated by MQ and by default the `MessageId` will be copied over to the `CorrelId` field of the COA report message, then "application A" reads this message either based on a GET by `CorrelId` or at least uses the `CorrelId` when it does read the message.

Comment: In the new use case the `CorrelId` will be set on the responses from both QM.B and QM.C to something completely different than the original `MessageId` and it will no longer be able to "correlate COAs" as you stated.  Turning off COA only for one will not solve the problem you would need it to be turned off for both.  If that is acceptable and you control the `RCVR` channel on QM.B this could be done.

Comment: The app would set a reporting option to get the COA message like `MQRO_COA`, and the default that goes along with that is `MQRO_COPY_MSG_ID_TO_CORREL_ID` and the behavior that most apps rely on and was the only COA behavior I was aware of (I didn't even realize there was a reporting option to tell it to copy MessageId to CorrelId).  In another SO answer recently I learned that you also have `MQRO_PASS_CORREL_ID` available.

Comment: If your app was already specifying `MQRO_PASS_CORREL_ID` today, the pub sub behavior I mentioned for MessageId also applies to CorrelId in that it will generate a new one for each published copy of the message.  But as of MQ v8 IBM KC states that you can set the SUB property `DESTCORL(000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)` [48 zeros] and then "the CorrelId set by the publishing application will be maintained in the copy of the message delivered to the subscription".  So in that case if your QM.B was upgraded to a supported version like v8 you could get it working.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc your hints were very helpful, investigation is on-going. Will share outcome when done.

Comment: Turning off COA only for one will not solve the problem you would need it to be turned off for both.  If that is acceptable and you control the RCVR channel on QM.B this could be done. Let me know if you want me to write up an answer with that solution?

Comment: @JoshMc, this would not be acceptable because App A relies on COA (and may be COD) in its processing logic e.g. request won’t be marked as successfullu processed until COA/COD received. But it would be helpful to know how to suppress COAs/CODs on the QM.B receiver channel level (I can control it) - could you advise?. BTW, I just realised that we don’t have sender channel from QM.C to the QM.B - does it mean that COAs from QM.C will be landing to the dead letter queue?

Comment: Actually the COA messages will go back to the `ReplyToQmgr/ReplyToQueue`, if that is QM.A, then you would need a channel from QM.C to QM.A for it to deliver COA messages.  I do think they would go to DLQ on QM.C if it didn't know how to get back to the `ReplyToQmgr` but with out a quick test I'm not certain.   Take a look at my answer to this other question "[JMS and IBM WebSphere not generating COD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619307/jms-and-ibm-websphere-not-generating-cod/43623153#43623153)" for some details on the removal of the COA reporting options.

Comment: Also note that you have other options that require something outside of MQ.  You could for instance follow a similar path to what you are doing but have a custom app read from the source queue and write to the down steam queues, if it has the correct permissions it can specify the same MessageID so COA would work.  There are programs that use MQ API exits to duplicate messages with out the need for a intermediate queue, CapitalWare sells one that can perform this function, the message can land in Q2 and a copy will be made to Q3.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc. Option outside MQ was on the table as the plan "B" (in fact there is a stereotype building block available, which is built to multiplicate data feeds), which is not desired from the architectural point of view, I was looking to duplicate the feed on MQ layer. And I'm somewhat disappointed with the MQ-specific compexities around that, in case of JMS such problem is solved as easy as creation of a JMS bridge. MQ looks much more complicated...

Comment: So what was the outcome of this for you?